# bound on entire function

Tags: complex-analysis

If f is an entire function such that for each fixed $z$ either $|f(z)|\leq 1 $ or $|f'(z)|\leq 1$ then prove that $f$ is a linear polynomial.

I guess something have to do with integration, but not getting what to do.

Comment: Are you familiar with Liouville's Theorem?

Comment: yes but how to use here ?

Comment: What you should get used to is problems where you see that $f(z)$ is entire and bounded. They almost always call for Liouville's Theorem.

Comment: wait, I think i stated the problem wrong. I didn't means either $f(z)\leq 1$ for all $z$ or... I meant for each $z$ either $f(z)\leq 1$ or.... I'm editing..

Comment: I would not say it was wrong. It was not very clear, but I for one  understood it just fine in the original version (since the other intepretation is not very natural, part of the condition being completely redundant). But it is clearer now, so +1 for the edit.

Answer (score 3):

For any $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$, consider the set $T$ and the number $\alpha$
defined by:

$$T = \big\{ t \in [0,1] : |f(tz)| \le 1 \big\}
\quad\text{ and }\quad
\alpha = \begin{cases} 
0, & T = \emptyset\\
\sup_{t \in T} t, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

It is clear $|f'(tz)| \le 1$ whenever $t \ge \alpha$. From this, we see

$$|f(z) - f(\alpha z)| = \left| \int_{\alpha}^1 f'(tz) z dt \right|
\le \int_{\alpha}^1 | f'(tz) z | dt \le |z|(1-\alpha) \le |z|$$

If $\alpha \ne 0$, then $|f(\alpha z)| \le 1$. This implies for all $z$, we have

$$|f(z)| \le |f(\alpha z)| + |f(z)- f(\alpha z)| \le \max(|f(0)|, 1) + |z|$$

For any $\zeta \in \mathbb{C}$ and $R \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $R > |\zeta|$.
By Cauchy integral formula for $f''(z)$, we have

$$f''(\zeta) = \frac{2!}{2\pi i}\int_{|z| = R} \frac{f(z)}{(z-\zeta)^3} dz\\
\implies
|f''(\zeta)| 
\le  \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{|z| = R} \frac{|f(z)|}{|z-\zeta|^3} |dz|
\le   \frac{2R(\max(|f(0)|,1) + |R|)}{(R-|\zeta|)^3}
$$
Sending $R \to \infty$, we find $f''(\zeta) = 0$ for any $\zeta$. As a result, $f(z)$ is a linear polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

Write your function as a power series.

In the first case, you get that $f$ is bounded. Use Liouville's theorem, what do you get?

If now, the derivative is bounded, what can you say about the derivative of an entire function? Is the derivative also holomorphic? Use Liouville's theorem again.

Comment: wait, I think i stated the problem wrong. I didn't means either $f(z)\leq 1$ for all $z$ or... I meant for each $z$ either $f(z)\leq 1$ or....

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is entire, so $f$ is analytic over the entire $\mathbb{C}$. This means that

$$f(z)=\sum^{\infty} a_n(z-z_0)^n$$

Now for starters, if $|f(z)|\leq 1$ over its entire domain, then it is bounded, and so by Liouville's Theorem it is just a constant (i.e. $f(z)=C$, and $C$ is just a complex number).

If, however, $|f'(z)|\leq 1$, then that means the derivative of that power-series is bounded. That means **that** must be a constant, and so the $a_1$ term (the $(z-z_0)$ coefficient) would be the only term that lives after saying that $f'(z)$ is constant.

Comment: The second thing that I said can also be understood as - *the derivative of a linear polynomial is just a constant, with that constant being the $(z-z_0)$ coefficient.*